# Two colors in one string with one function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This sounds like a very easy problem to solve. Admittedly I had hoped to be able to do as much. I want to have one string, with two colors. In JS:

```
function twoColors(s1,s2) {
    s1.color = "#hexColor1";
    s2.color = "#hexColor2";
    return(s1+s2)
}
```

in HTML (after sourcing in JS)

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("theElementsID").innerHTML = twoColors("one","two");
</script>
```

Yet this doesn't work...
Ideas?

Comment: Strings don't have colors.  You need to write HTML tags with CSS.

Comment: It probably works just as expected, but `s1` and `s2` are strings, and you've for some reason added a `color` property to strings

Comment: @j08691 sorry I didn't copy-paste the function in there, but it is in my code.

Comment: @SLaks so how would I do that?

Comment: You can do it with DOM scripting: https://jsfiddle.net/odq8p444/

Comment: Only replace the function for this:                                                         function twoColors(s1, s2) {
 return(s1.fontcolor("#ab0000") + s2.fontcolor("#039"));
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the text in HTML with a style.

```js
function twoColors(s1, s2) {
  s1 = "<span style=\"color:#eeff00\">" + s1 + "</span>";
  s2 = "<span style=\"color:#00eeff\">" + s2 + "</span>";
  return (s1 + s2)
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = twoColors("one", "two");
```

```html
<div id="output" style="background-color:black;">123</div>
```

Comment: What is with the + s1 +?

Comment: you need to see it like this: `s1 = string + variable + string`

Answer (score 1):

If there's a good reason not to use css, then you can do:

```js
function twoColors(s1,s2) {
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  var el1 = document.createElement('span');
      el1.style.color = "#33aa33";
      el1.textContent = s1;
  container.appendChild(el1);
  var el2 = document.createElement('span');
      el2.style.color = "#aa3333";
      el2.textContent = s2;
  container.appendChild(el2)
  return(container)
}
document.getElementById("theElementID").appendChild(twoColors("one","two"));
```

```html
<div id="theElementID"></div>
```